# JSON file will not give values back into html section?

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
<?php
$data= file_get_contents('blogData.json');
echo($data);
?>
```

========Next Section==========

```
<?php
    $data= file_get_contents('blogData.json' , true);
    $decodedData= json_decode($data, true);
    $countID = count((array)$decodedData) + 1;
    $decodedData[$countID] = array('id' => $countID, 'title' => $_POST['postTitle'], 'author' => $_POST['postauthor'], 'desc' => $_POST['postdescription'], 'post' => $_POST['blogPost']);
    file_put_contents('blogData.json' , json_encode($decodedData));
    console.log($decodedData);
    header('Location:Blog.php');
?>
```

===========================

```
<script type="javascript/text">
$.getJSON("proxy.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        $('#posts').append('<h3>' + entry.id + '</h3>');
        $('#posts').append('<h4>' + entry.author + '</h4>');
        $('#posts').append('<h4>' + entry.desc + '</h4>');
        $('#posts').append('<h4>' + entry.post + '</h4>');
    })
});
</script>
```

I am attempting to return the JSON file into blog posts and do not know why they wont return?
I would like the blog posts to appear in the blank red box
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU7gj.png)

Comment: You should be aware that there's a race condition in the code.  Without a lock of some kind, or a transactional model for your data, 2 requests to save a post couple overwrite each other.  If you don't want to add a database server to your architecture, you might consider using sqlite instead - it's file based, but addresses the race condition.

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: I have editted my post with a picture of the behaviour

Comment: That screenshot tells me even less than it tells you.  You'll have to determine what's failing before can determine why it looks like that.

Comment: The site posts to the JSON file but fails to call it back from the file when i wish to display it